# Can the Surface Pro - Intel 7th Gen Core m3-7Y30 2.6 GHz, 4 GB RAM, 128 GB SSD run Microsoft SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, cpu

I would really like a surface pro, but I need to run SQL server.

I just wanted to know if the specs I posted in the question are sufficient enough to run SQL server smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's way more than enough. SQL server itself doesn't need much resources, although it really depends on how much data you put in it and what kind of queries you run